# Processing isn't loading videos

Tags: processing

I'm using Processing 4.0b7 (also tried with previous versions), and installed its Video Library. I have the following code (Im literally just trying to play a video):

```
import processing.video.*;
Movie video;

void setup() {
  size(640, 480);
  video = new Movie(this, "video.mp4");
  video.play();
}

void draw() {
  if (video.available()) {
    video.read();
    image(video, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

I have "video.mp4" on a folder named data, on the same file as the sketch.
Whenever I try to run the code, I get the following error:

```
(java.exe:28748): GLib-CRITICAL **: 19:04:53.545: g_dir_open_with_errno: assertion 'wpath != NULL' failed
Cannot load GStreamer plugins from C:\Users\Estêvão\Documents\Processing\libraries\video\library\windows-amd64\gstreamer-1.0
Processing video library using bundled GStreamer 1.16.2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such Gstreamer factory: playbin
    at org.freedesktop.gstreamer.ElementFactory.makeRawElement(ElementFactory.java:307)
    at org.freedesktop.gstreamer.Element.makeRawElement(Element.java:104)
    at org.freedesktop.gstreamer.elements.PlayBin.<init>(PlayBin.java:118)
    at processing.video.Movie.initGStreamer(Unknown Source)
    at processing.video.Movie.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at ex5_2_1.setup(ex5_2_1.java:26)
    at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2142)
    at processing.awt.PSurfaceAWT$9.callDraw(PSurfaceAWT.java:1440)
    at processing.core.PSurfaceNone$AnimationThread.run(PSurfaceNone.java:356)
RuntimeException: Could not load movie file video.mp4
RuntimeException: Could not load movie file video.mp4
RuntimeException: Could not load movie file video.mp4
```

I'm using Windows 11. I think the problem is coming from the library instalation, but I've asked for friends who have their video working to send me their Processing files, and I'm still getting the same problem. Also deleted everything Processing-related and reinstalled it several times, and I still can't get it to work. Other libraries such as sound are working.

Answer (score 2):

I've finally solved the problem.
The sketch was on a folder with special characters. I had already changed the name of the folder, but I kept getting the same bug, so I assumed that wasn't the problem.
But well, my name has a special character as well, therefore, so does my username. Processing goes through the Windows user folder before getting to the sketch folder, and turns out that's what was making the program not work.
Thank you all for your help, anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I won't have the time to debug this in detail (e.g. if it's something to do with special(unicode) characters in paths or something deeper within the processing-video library).

For now I suggest using an older version of Processing.
I can confirm the video library works on Windows 11 with [Processing 3.5.4](https://github.com/processing/processing/releases/download/processing-0270-3.5.4/processing-3.5.4-windows64.zip) and the [Procecessing video 2.0 library](https://github.com/processing/processing-video/releases/download/latest-processing3/video.zip) (Thank you @cSharp for the helpful comments)

**Update** I can confirm you can use [Processing video 2.1](https://github.com/processing/processing-video/releases/download/latest/video.zip) with Processing 4.0b7 on Windows 11.

You would need to:

1. remove the current video library
2. unzip video.zip (link to video version 2.1 for Processing4 above)
3. restart Processing (if you had it open already)

You can run your code or **Processing > Examples > Contributed Libraries > Video Library for Processing 4 > Movie > Loop** to test.

Comment: I can confirm the video library **for Processing 4** `4.2.1` works with Processing `4.0b7` on MacOS Monterey `12.2.1`.  I do not have any special characters in path to the sketch or video.

Comment: Note: there seems to be 2 different video libraries, one for Processing 3 and another for Processing 4.